# SystemVerilog, if-statements order inside an always_comb block

Tags: if-statement, system-verilog, fsm

I am new to SystemVerilog and I would like to know how multiple assignments to the same signal are handled inside an always_comb block.

I am analyzing an FSM written by someonelse and I don't understand which would be the next state (signal named "ctrl_fsm_ns") if all the if-statements are true. Searching on google, I found out that here blocking assignments are used, so I expect that the last if-statement will decide the next state (so it is like a certain priority is assigned to each if-statement). But what if inside each if-block different signals are asserted? They will be all asserted even if the next state will be the last one, for example?

Here is the piece of code I don't understand.

```
always_comb
begin
  ...
  unique case (ctrl_fsm_cs)
   ...
   FIRST_FETCH:
   begin
    is_decoding_o = 1'b0;
    // Stall because of IF miss
    if ((id_ready_i == 1'b1) )
    begin
      ctrl_fsm_ns = DECODE;
    end

    // handle interrupts
    if (irq_req_ctrl_i & irq_enable_int) begin
      // This assumes that the pipeline is always flushed before
      // going to sleep.
      ctrl_fsm_ns = IRQ_TAKEN_IF;
      halt_if_o   = 1'b1;
      halt_id_o   = 1'b1;
    end

    if ((debug_req_pending || trigger_match_i) & (~debug_mode_q))
    begin
      ctrl_fsm_ns = DBG_TAKEN_IF;
      halt_if_o   = 1'b1;
      halt_id_o   = 1'b1;
    end

   end
```

Comment: I haven't run the simulation, I don't have the simulator at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

For each variable in the always_comb block, the last assignment is the final value. The tool analyzes the procedural flow to make sure every variable that is being assigned has at least one assignment in every possible flow through the code. If there is any possibility that a variable could be read without being written to, that is considered latch behavior and would be illegal for an always_comb block.

You need to look at the code before or after the case statement to see if there are any other assignments to the `halt_` variables.

---

An example based on your comments:

```
always_comb begin
  A = 0; B = 1; C = 2;
  if (I) A = X;
  if (J) B = Y;
  if (K) begin B = Z; C = Z; end
end
```

That is equivalent to these three continuous assignments:

```
assign A = I ? X : 0;
assign B = K ? Z : (J ? Y : 1 );
assign C = K ? Z : 2;
```

Each `if` statement becomes a multiplexor, and the latter statements have the higher priority.

Comment: Yes, all the variables have the default values assigned before the case statement. Now I have a question, for example, if the first if-block contains "my_signal = 1'b1" and all the if-conditions are true, at the end the signal my_signal will have the value 1'b1 or the default value, since it is not assigned in the last if-blocks?

Comment: I think you are over thinking this. For each variable, you need to trace the entire flow of procedural code in the `always_comb` block. Last assignment wins.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. It is difficult to explain my doubt, sorry. I mean, I have 3 signal (named A, B and C) and an always_comb block where there are 3 uncorrelated if-statemnt

Comment: My answer remains the same. Go to http://www.edaplayground.com and try some code.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. It is difficult to explain my doubt, sorry. I mean, I have 3 signal (named A, B and C) and an always_comb block where there are 3 uncorrelated if-stmnt which can be all true at the same time. Let's suppose that inside each if-block, respectively, A, B and C are asserted to 1. So, if only the first if-stmnt is true, then only A is asserted; if only the last if-stmnt is true, then only C is asserted to 1. And what about the scenario where all the 3 if-statements are true (supposing that at the beginning of the always_comb, signals A, B and C are assigned to 0 by default)?

Comment: When you say that _signals A, B and C are assigned to 0 by default_, I'm assuming that means you have made an assignment to each variable before any `if` statement. Then there can be no combination of `if` statements being all false, one true, two true, or all true where there is no assignment to variable A in the `always_comb` block.  If you still don't understand, ask another question with a complete example using variables A,B, and C.

Answer (score 0):

Your question to the code above is a general programming question and not Verilog-specific. Because there are only blocking assignments in use, the code is entirely procedural.

Since the code isn't using an "if-else-if" sequence, but just "if-if-if", all the "if" conditions will be evaluated IN ORDER, and all assignments will happen IN ORDER, thus the final assignment will win out (as Dave said).

In your comments above you asked about what if (A_expr,B_expr,C_expr) where all true? Then (A,B,C) will all be set to 1.

```
A_expr=1; B_expr=1; C_expr=1;

if (A_expr) A = 1;
if (B_expr) B = 1;
if (C_expr) C = 1;
```